# What details do I need to add to my question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158071/are-there-any-common-powders-that-dissolve-in-oil) today and then the question was closed stating that I need to add more details. To me, the question is perfectly clear, so I'm probably missing what information is missing. Could anyone explain what details I should add?

Comment: It seems a bit broad to me (lists of 'what compound satisfies this property' are naturally broad), but clear.

Comment: I will reopen the question, I agree with @orthocresol and I think it deserves a shot.

Comment: Just an opinion, since I did not vote to close, but it seems the application might be important, and other factors that would limit the choice of additive.

Comment: Agreed- any bonus context / extra details is always a good idea as it narrows the possibilities

Comment: @BuckThorn (and others) Thanks for the suggestions. I finally got back to this and rewrote the question to be more about the application. I hope that makes for a better question